# Paragraph Spacing in the IEEEtran class using LaTeX

Tags: spacing, ieeetran

I am trying to correct a spacing requirement for an IEEE conference. I am using the `IEEEtran` class. I only want to change the spacing of a regular paragraph and not the spacing after a subsection.

Basic working code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\section{Ease of Use}

\subsection{Maintaining the Integrity of the Specifications}

The IEEEtran class file is used to format your paper and style the text. 
All margins, column widths, line spaces, and text fonts are prescribed; please do not alter them. You may note peculiarities. 

For example, the head margin measures proportionately more than is customary. 
This measurement and others are deliberate, using specifications that anticipate your paper as one part of the entire proceedings.

\end{document}
```

[image: This image shows the spacing that I need.]

[image: But, this is the one that I keep getting.]

The top picture shows the spacing that I want and the bottom one shows what I keep getting from LaTeX. I am unable to change this to match the given format.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please provide some working code; see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/117534)

Comment: I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: the only reason to use a publisher class is to remove choice from the author and enforce the publisher's style rules, are you sure you want to change the spacing? it is normally strongly advised not to change the layout in such a class.

Comment: I do not want to change the spacing, but the ieee conference wants me to change and add that space.

Comment: In the .cls file , parskip is set to 0 ec , and a minute stretchability/shrinkability. With the code you posted, I can see no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do it, just change the `parskip` value to whatever they ask you to do.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\begin{document}

\section{Ease of Use}

\subsection{Maintaining the Integrity of the Specifications}

The IEEEtran class file is used to format your paper and style the text. 
All margins, column widths, line spaces, and text fonts are prescribed; please do not alter them. You may note peculiarities.

For example, the head margin measures proportionately more than is customary. 
This measurement and others are deliberate, using specifications that anticipate your paper as one part of the entire proceedings.

\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Update:**

Based on the OP comments below, here are two possible solutions. The easiest would be to add `\medskip`, e.g., between two paragraphs without changing `\parskip` value like this:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\section{Ease of Use}

\subsection{Maintaining the Integrity of the Specifications}

The IEEEtran class file is used to format your paper and style the text. 
All margins, column widths, line spaces, and text fonts are prescribed; please do not alter them. You may note peculiarities.
\medskip  % <------- HERE

For example, the head margin measures proportionately more than is customary. 
This measurement and others are deliberate, using specifications that anticipate your paper as one part of the entire proceedings.

\end{document}
```

> [image]

As another option, you can use `titlesec` package and play with the spacings around `section`s, `subsection`s, `subsubsection`s, etc.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}    
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

\newcommand{\subparagraph}{} % <--- define a subparagraph because ieeetran doesn't have it
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.0ex plus .5ex minus .2ex}{\dimexpr1.0ex-6pt plus .2ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2.0ex plus .5ex minus .2ex}{\dimexpr1.0ex-6pt plus .2ex}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\dimexpr2.0ex-6pt plus .5ex minus .1ex}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Ease of Use}

\subsection{Maintaining the Integrity of the Specifications}

The IEEEtran class file is used to format your paper and style the text. 
All margins, column widths, line spaces, and text fonts are prescribed; please do not alter them. You may note peculiarities.
\medskip

For example, the head margin measures proportionately more than is customary. 
This measurement and others are deliberate, using specifications that anticipate your paper as one part of the entire proceedings.

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

If I do this, the spacing under the subsection increases as well. However, as per my second screenshot, I don't want the spacing for the part below the subsection change. 

I only want the spacing for a regular paragraph change.

Comment: Hello. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to add `\medskip` between two paragraphs and don't change `\parskip` value. Other than that, you can use `titlesec` package and play with the spacings around sections, subsections, subsubsections, etc.

Comment: @BhaskarGhosh: Please see my update!